# Voucher Management System ( A web app with ReactJS front-end)

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am quite new to Javascript and ReactJS. I have decided to take the ReactJS route, learn and build something relevant as well. Some feedback on how my approach can be improved is much appreciated.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var Catalyst = require('react-catalyst');
var Axios = require('axios');
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';

ReactModal.setAppElement('#main');

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <OrganisationsTable/>
    }
}

class OrganisationsTable extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        Axios.get(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations").then((response)=>{
            this.originalList = response.data;
            this.setState({
                organisations : response.data,
                showLoading:false,
                showAddForm:false
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            alert(error);
        });
        this.state = {searchString:"",organisations:[],showLoading:true};
        this.searchOrgansiastions = this.searchOrgansiastions.bind(this);
        this.showForm = this.showForm.bind(this);
        this.closeForm = this.closeForm.bind(this);
        this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this);
    }

    updateList(organisation){
        let newList = this.state.organisations
        organisation.id = newList.length +1;
        newList.push(organisation);
        this.setState({
            organisations : newList
        });
    }

    showForm(){

        this.setState({
            showAddForm:true
        });
    }

    closeForm(){
        this.setState({
            showAddForm:false
        });
    }

    searchOrgansiastions(evt){
        var result = [];
        var searchTerm = evt.target.value; 
        if(searchTerm.length == 0){
            result = this.originalList;

        }else{

            this.originalList.map((organisation)=>{
                if(organisation.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                    result.push(organisation);
                }
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            searchString : evt.target.value,
            organisations : result
        });

    }




    render(){

        return (

        <div>

        {this.state.showLoading ?
            <ReactLoading className="offset-md-6" type="bars" color="#444" /> : 
            <div>
        <div style={{marginTop: 2 + 'em'}}  className="form-group row">
            <div className="offset-md-3 col-6">
            <input type="text" name="organisationSearch" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.searchOrgansiastions} className="form-control" id="organisationSearch" placeholder="Search Organisations"/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showForm} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Add Voucher</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table className="table table-hover ">
            <thead className="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Code
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Parent
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.state.organisations.map((organisation)=>{
                    return <OrganisationRow data={organisation}/>

                })}
            </tbody>

        </table>
        </div>

        }
        <ReactModal 
                isOpen={this.state.showAddForm}
                contentLabel="Inline Styles Modal Example"
                style={{
                    overlay: {
                        backgroundColor: 'gray',
                    }
                }}>
                    <h3> Add New Voucher</h3>
                    <CreateOrganisation  updateList={this.updateList}/>
                     <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.closeForm}>Close</button> 
        </ReactModal>
        </div>

        );

    }

}

class CreateOrganisation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let today = new Date();
        this.state = {organisations:[],showLoading:true,buttonDisabled:true,selectedOrganisatonId:"",voucherValue:"",
        dateText:today.getFullYear()+"-"+today.getMonth()+"-"+today.getDate()}
        Axios.get(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/all").then((response)=>{
            this.originalList = response.data;
            this.setState({
                organisations : response.data,
                showLoading:false,
                buttonDisabled:false
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            alert(error);
        });
        this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
        this.handleChanges = this.handleChanges.bind(this);
    }
    submitForm(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.voucherValue);
        if(!isNaN(this.state.voucherValue) && parseInt(this.state.voucherValue) > 0){
            this.setState({
                buttonDisabled:true
            })
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("value",this.state.voucherValue);
            Axios.post(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/"+this.state.selectedOrganisatonId+"/vouchers",
        formData,{headers:{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then((response)=>{

            window.location.reload();

            }).catch((error)=>{
                alert(error);
                this.setState({
                    buttonDisabled:false
                })
            });
        }else{
            alert("Error in value. Either not numeric, equal 0 or below 0")
        }

    }

    handleChanges(evt){
        if(evt.target.id == "organisationSelector"){
            this.setState({
                selectedOrganisatonId : evt.target.value
            })
        }else if(evt.target.id == "valueInput"){
            this.setState({
                voucherValue : evt.target.value
            })
        }

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{marginTop: 5 + 'em'}}>
            { this.state.showLoading ?
            <ReactLoading className="offset-md-6" type="bars" color="#444" /> : 
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="organisationSelector">Organistion</label>
                    <select onChange={this.handleChanges} value={this.state.selectedOrganisatonId} className="form-control" id="organisationSelector">
                        {this.state.organisations.map((organisation)=>{
                            return <option value={organisation.id}>{organisation.name}</option>
                        })}    
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="valueInput">Value:</label>
                    <input value={this.state.voucherValue} onChange={this.handleChanges} type="text" className="form-control" id="valueInput" placeholder="Value"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="valueInput">Value:</label>
                    <input value={this.state.dateText} disabled={true} type="text" className="form-control" id="valueInput" placeholder="Value"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                <button disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class OrganisationRow extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.showVouchers = this.showVouchers.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);

    }
    showVouchers(){
        this.setState({
            showModal:true
        });
    }
    handleCloseModal(){
        this.setState({
            showModal:false
        });
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <tr>
                <td> {this.props.data.id}</td>
                <td> {this.props.data.code}</td>
                <td> {this.props.data.name}</td>
                <td> {this.props.data["parent"] !== undefined? this.props.data.parent.name : ""}</td>
                <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showVouchers} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
                View Vouchers
                </button></td>
                <td>
                    <ReactModal 
                    isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                    contentLabel="Inline Styles Modal Example"
                    style={{
                        overlay: {
                            backgroundColor: 'gray',

                        }
                        }}
                    >
                    <VouchersList organisation={this.props.data}/>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close</button>
                    </ReactModal>
                </td>

            </tr>

        );

    }
}
class VouchersList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {vouchers:[],showLoading:true};
        Axios.get(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/"+this.props.organisation.id+"/vouchers").then((response)=>{
            this.setState({
                vouchers : response.data,
                showLoading:false
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            alert(error);
        });
        this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this);
    }

    updateList(voucher){
        let newList = this.state.vouchers;
        voucher.id = newList.length +1;
        newList.push(voucher);
        this.setState({vouchers:newList});
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <h3>{this.props.organisation.name}  {this.props.organisation["parent"] !== undefined ? "| " + this.props.organisation.parent.name : ""}</h3>

            { this.state.showLoading ?
            <ReactLoading className="offset-md-6" type="bars" color="#444" /> : 


            <table style={{width:800 ,marginTop: 5 + 'em'}} className="table table-hover ">
            <thead className="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Created Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Value
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {this.state.vouchers.map((voucher=>{
                    return <VoucherItem organisation={this.props.organisation} data={voucher} />
                }))}
                <VoucherInput updateList={this.updateList} organisationId={this.props.organisation.id}/>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            }
            </div>


        );
    }
}

class VoucherItem extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {transactions:[],showTransactions : false, voucherValue : this.props.data.value}
        this.showTransactions = this.showTransactions.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
        this.updateVoucher = this.updateVoucher.bind(this);

    }
    showTransactions(){
        this.setState({
            showTransactions : true
        })
    }
    handleCloseModal(){
        this.setState({
            showTransactions : false
        })
    }
    updateVoucher(transactionValue){
        let value = parseInt(this.state.voucherValue) + parseInt(transactionValue);
        this.setState({
            voucherValue: value.toString()
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(

            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.created_date}</td>
                <td>{this.state.voucherValue}</td>
                <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showTransactions} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
                View Transactions
                </button></td>
                <td><ReactModal 
                    isOpen={this.state.showTransactions}
                    contentLabel="Inline Styles Modal Example"
                    style={{
                        overlay: {
                            backgroundColor: 'gray',

                        }
                        }}
                    >
                    <TransactionsList updateVoucher={this.updateVoucher} organisation={this.props.organisation} voucher={this.props.data}/>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close</button>
                    </ReactModal></td>
            </tr>





        );
    }
}

class VoucherInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let today = new Date();
        this.state = {buttonDisabled:false,
            dateText:today.getFullYear()+"-"+today.getMonth()+"-"+today.getDate(),
            voucherValue:"",
            valueInputClass:"form-control",
            }
        this.addVoucher = this.addVoucher.bind(this);
        this.handleValue = this.handleValue.bind(this);
    }
    addVoucher(){

        if( !isNaN(this.state.voucherValue) && this.state.voucherValue.length != 0 ){
            console.log(this.state.voucherValue);
            if(parseInt(this.state.voucherValue) >0 ){
            this.setState({
                buttonDisabled:true
            })
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("value",this.state.voucherValue);
            Axios.post(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/"+this.props.organisationId+"/vouchers",
        formData,{headers:{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then((response)=>{
            let voucher = {}
            voucher["created_date"] = this.state.dateText;
            voucher["value"] = this.state.voucherValue;
            this.props.updateList(voucher);
            let today = new Date();
            this.setState(
                {buttonDisabled:false,
            dateText:today.getFullYear()+"-"+today.getMonth()+"-"+today.getDate(),
            voucherValue:"",
            valueInputClass:"form-control",
            }
            )

            }).catch((error)=>{
                alert(error);
                this.setState({
                    buttonDisabled:false
                })
            });
            }else{
                alert("Voucher Value can't be below or equal to 0");
            }

        }
    }

    handleValue(evt){

        let normal = "form-control";
        let withError = "form-control has-danger";
        let selectedClass = "";
        if( isNaN(evt.target.value ) || parseInt(evt.target.value) <= 0 ){ 
            selectedClass = withError;
        }else{
            selectedClass = normal;
        }
        this.setState({
            voucherValue : evt.target.value,
            valueInputClass:selectedClass
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>Create New Voucher</td>

                <td>
                    <div className="form-contrl">
                    <input disabled={true} type="text" value={this.state.dateText} className="form-control" id="dateInput" />
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div className={this.state.valueInputClass}>
                    <input type="text" name="valueInput" value={this.state.voucherValue} onChange={this.handleValue} className="form-control" id="valueInput" placeholder="Enter Value example (10)"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><button disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addVoucher} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class TransactionsList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {showLoading:true,transactions : []};
        Axios.get(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/"+this.props.organisation.id+"/vouchers/"+this.props.voucher.id+"/transactions").then((response)=>{
            this.setState({
                transactions : response.data,
                showLoading : false
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            alert(error);
        });
        this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this);
    }
    updateList(transaction){
        let newList = this.state.transactions
        transaction.id = newList.length+1;
        newList.push(transaction);
        // Update Voucher
        this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
            transactions: newList
        }));
        this.props.updateVoucher(transaction.transaction_value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <h3>Vocher : {this.props.voucher.id}</h3>

            { this.state.showLoading ?
            <ReactLoading  className="offset-md-2" type="bars" color="#444" /> : 


            <table style={{width:800 ,marginTop: 5 + 'em'}} className="table table-hover ">
            <thead className="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Value
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {this.state.transactions.map((transaction=>{
                    return <TransactionItem voucherId={this.props.voucher.id} transaction={transaction}/> 
                }))}
                <TransactionInput voucherValue={this.props.voucher.value} organisationId={this.props.organisation.id} voucherId={this.props.voucher.id} updateList = {this.updateList} />
             </tbody>
            </table>
            }
            </div>


        );
    }
}

class TransactionItem extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.transaction.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.transaction.description}</td>
                <td>{this.props.transaction.transaction_value}</td>
                {/* <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.deleteTransaction} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Delete</button></td> */}

            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class TransactionInput extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {buttonDisabled:false,descriptionString:"",transactionValue:"",valueInputClass:"form-control",descriptionInputClass:"form-control"}
        this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
        this.handleValue = this.handleValue.bind(this);
        this.addTransaction = this.addTransaction.bind(this);

    }

    addTransaction(){

        if( !isNaN(this.state.transactionValue) && this.state.descriptionString.length <= 250 && this.state.descriptionString.length != 0 && this.state.transactionValue.length != 0 ){
            if(parseInt(this.props.voucherValue) + parseInt(this.state.transactionValue) >= 0){
            this.setState({
                buttonDisabled:true
            })
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("transaction_value",this.state.transactionValue);
            formData.append("description",this.state.descriptionString);
            Axios.post(window.location.href.replace("3000","8000")+"organisations/"+this.props.organisationId+"/vouchers/"+this.props.voucherId+"/transactions",
        formData,{headers:{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then((response)=>{
            let transaction = {};
            transaction["voucher_id"] = this.props.voucherId;
            transaction["transaction_value"] = this.state.transactionValue;
            transaction["description"] = this.state.descriptionString;
            this.props.updateList(transaction);
            this.setState({buttonDisabled:false,descriptionString:"",transactionValue:"",valueInputClass:"form-control",descriptionInputClass:"form-control"})

            }).catch((error)=>{
                alert(error);
                this.setState({
                    buttonDisabled:false
                })
            });
            }else{
                alert("Voucher Value can't be below 0. Amend transaction value");
            }

        }
    }

    handleDescription(evt){
        let normal = "form-control";
        let withError = "form-control has-danger";
        let selectedClass = "";
        if(evt.target.value.length > 250){
            selectedClass = withError;
        }else{
            selectedClass = normal;
        }
        this.setState({
            descriptionString : evt.target.value,
            descriptionInputClass : selectedClass
        })
    }

    handleValue(evt){
        let normal = "form-control";
        let withError = "form-control has-danger";
        let selectedClass = "";
        if( isNaN(evt.target.value )){
            selectedClass = withError;
        }else{
            selectedClass = normal;
        }
        this.setState({
            transactionValue : evt.target.value,
            valueInputClass:selectedClass
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>Create New Transaction</td>

                <td>
                    <div className={this.state.descriptionInputClass}>
                    <input type="text" name="descriptionInput" value={this.state.descriptionString} onChange={this.handleDescription} className="form-control" id="organisationSearch" placeholder="Enter Description"/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div className={this.state.valueInputClass}>
                    <input type="text" name="valueInput" value={this.state.transactionValue} onChange={this.handleValue} className="form-control" id="organisationSearch" placeholder="Enter Value example (-10 or 10)"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><button disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addTransaction} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
ReactDom.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('main'));
```

Pitfalls I identified:

1. Components can be separated into different files to increase readability
2. Some components share the rendering logic and I am considering making a super class and inherit it with the extra handling logic. For example, all the tables and the table items render in the same way so they can be a child of a table parent and a table item parent.[Taken from my Java background]

This is the front-end code only. The backend is done using Python-Flask and can't be shared.